# Is my hard drive salvageable?

Tags: windows, hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery, hardware-rec, testdisk

I was backing up a folder from my Android phone to my storage drive and it was taking forever so I cancelled it from the copy dialog, windows explorer hung so I opened task manager and restarted it, afterwards I went to the directory I was copying to and deleted the files that it had managed to copy. My computer became very slow, so unknowingly I restarted my computer.

My computer took an excessively long amount of time to boot, once in Windows I looked for the drive but could not find it so I opened up the partition manager and it prompted me to reinitialize the drive, I immediately discerned that would be destructive to the data on the drive so I shutdown windows and created a alt Linux rescue bootable flash drive and booted to it.

Currently I am running a quick search on the drive with test disk and it seems like it will take about 11 days at this rate.

Should I wait for the quick scan to complete?
Or is there something else I should be doing instead.

Comment: Keep in mind that if the data is really valuable to you, stop all activities on the drive and power it down. Any usage of the drive could be further destroying your data. Seek a professional data recovery service. If the data is disposable then you should determine the health of the disc, specifically if it is physically failing from bad sectors. You can use the HD manufacturer's tools, hdd regenerator, mhdd, or a number of tools to perform a surface scan. Hiren's boot disc is one source. If there are several bad sectors you should stop all activity and consider next steps, like cloning.

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on how much money you want to spend.

Professional data recovery services can retrieve just about anything if your will to pay $$$$.

You could try spinrite from grc.com by steve gibson.  His product has a large user base which people have reported it saving their data.  I think its $69.99 or so.

If you have many bad sectors you will just have to be patient, as it will take a long time.